# How do I make an image move to the side, depending on which key has been pressed?

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have an image loaded on the canvas, however it has made a duplicate of it and there are two. And the image does not move at all on command either. Please help

```
   let img = document.getElementById("ship");
let player = {
  x: 375,
  y: 550,
  w: 50,
  h: 50,
};
requestAnimationFrame(draw);

function draw() {
  ctx.drawImage(img, 5, 5);
  ctx.img(player.x, player.y, player.w, player.h);
  //Draw

  //Request another frame
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

document.addEventListener("keydown", move);

function move(event) {
  if (event.code == "ArrowRight") {
    player.x = player.x + 50;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the keycodes in order to move, here they are.

```
down arrow  37
up arrow    38
right arrow 39
down arrow  40
```

Change your code to the following and it should work.

```
function move(event) {
  if (event.code === 39) {
    player.x = player.x + 50;
  }
}
```

Not sure why you have two images but the following lines will cause an issue

```
  ctx.drawImage(img, 5, 5);
  ctx.img(player.x, player.y, player.w, player.h);
```

You only need this,

```
ctx.drawImage(img, player.x, player.y, player.w, player.h);
```

`ctx.img` isn't a valid context function either.

[drawImage docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage)